# Call a function before server restart Node/Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm pooling with mysql and would like to end the connection if the server goes down.

The reason I'm doing this is that if the server is offline, the connection pool processes are still there, giving me a max_user_connections error when reconnecting.

I'm using connection.release() but apparently it is not good enough.

Is there a way to do this or a better solution for doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried listening to the "error" event on the connection? As for release not being good enough, [this bug](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1873) is still open, so that could be the reason.

Comment: Interesting. That works but if the server don't break it won't call getConnection again, leaving the pool empty. Will work on that though

Answer (score 0):

Try using `connection.end()` or `connection.destroy()`, as shown in the docs here https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#terminating-connections

Comment: Tried that. But my question is exactly to know if there is a function to call these ones before the server restarts or goes offline.For example when I kill an instance.

Comment: Hmm ok, good to know. I don't have an answer to that off the top of my head, but if I find any additional information I will update my answer.

Comment: Cool! Thank you for the help!